# Cannot complete installation on Surface Pro 4 as TypeCover isn't working for encrypted password

Tags: system-installation, surface-tablet

I just tried to install eOS on my Surface Pro 4. I selected encryption for the installation, and know my password. However, when I try to complete the installation I am not able to type anything. The TypeCover keyboard doesn't seem to work here.

It does work when I enter the Surface UEFI system configuration, however.

What do I do? Help, please!

Answer (score 1):

the only option to get through it the first time would be with another basic USB keyboard.

If you get that far there has is the below workaround in 18.04 to get the on-screen keyboard to work.

https://www.reddit.com/r/SurfaceLinux/comments/8kfpna/fixing_the_keyboard_for_booting_luks_full_disk/